# how to use .filter to edit a state in react without mutating

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, object, filter

Im not sure if this is even possible as I dont think `.filter` can be used for something like this. If I have an array like so:

```
abc: [
    {number: 1, letter: "a"},
    {number: 2, letter: "b"},
    {number: 3, letter: "c"},
    {number: 4, letter: "d"},
]
```

I want to do something like this

```
abc.filter(item => {
        if(item.number == 1){
            
            item.letter == "aa"
        }
    })
```

Basically updating the first element in the object to be `{number:1, letter:"aa"}`. However this ends up giving me an empty array. I dont think im going about it in the correct way. How could I use `filter` to make edits to certain elements?

Comment: Do you want to leave the other elements alone? That is, the result should have 4 items in the array, with the first with a changed `letter` property?

Comment: yes I want to leave the other elements alone. Only thing that should change is the first element and its `letter` prop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.filter` is not really appropriate here because that would create a new array with only the elements fulfilling the condition, which would then have to be put back into the original array somehow - possible, but convoluted. Map the array instead - if the condition is fulfilled, return a changed object.

Remember that in React, you should avoid mutation - don't assign to a property of an existing object, create a new one instead.

```js
const abc = [
    {number: 1, letter: "a"},
    {number: 2, letter: "b"},
    {number: 3, letter: "c"},
    {number: 4, letter: "d"},
];
const newArr = abc
  .map(obj =>
    obj.number === 1
    ? { ...obj, letter: 'aa' }
    : obj
  );
console.log(newArr);
```

Comment: this works! I would like to understand how this code works though. What exactly is happening with the spread operator? and do you need to return the original `obj` if the condition is not met?

Comment: `{ ...obj, letter: 'aa' }` creates a new object, with all the properties of the original object, and then adds/changes one more property: `letter: 'aa'` that gets put on the new object. It's the immutable way of adjusting an object. Yes, the `: obj` at the end returns the original.